# SQL Server Flatten Data - Get Data About a Table and Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to get data about a particular given schema and table name. The information I need is column names, data types, nullable or not, and whether it's a foreign or primary key. I've gotten close with the following query:

```
SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME, C.DATA_TYPE, C.IS_NULLABLE, CASE WHEN Z.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_PRIMARY_KEY, 
CASE WHEN Z.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_FOREIGN_KEY 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C 
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME, TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC 
        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE As CCU ON CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        WHERE TC.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA AND TC.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME 
        AND (TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' or TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY') 
        AND CCU.COLUMN_NAME = C.COLUMN_NAME)
    AS Z 
WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'ProductExpert' 
AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Learning' ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

This gathers the data I need, but it's not "flattened". See image of results:

[image: Results]

What I need ideally is for each column to be listed 1 time. In this instance ProductId AND OrganizationExpertId would be listed once with a 1 in IS_PRIMARY_KEY and IS_FOREIGN_KEY. I would still expect ExpertRoles to be in the return with a 0 for both.

Comment: Use `group by` on things that you know are always the same. Use `MAX` on things that should be 1 if 0 and 1 shows up. You have a column that is a primary key _and_ a foreign key? Or is that just an example

Comment: Not an example. There are many tables with primary/foreign keys as a single column. Group by and Max is a great suggestion. I will fiddle with that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of the join syntax. you need to change your joins in the way below:

```
SELECT 
  C.COLUMN_NAME, 
  C.DATA_TYPE, 
  C.IS_NULLABLE, 
  CASE WHEN PKEY.CONSTRAINT_NAME IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IS_PRIMARY_KEY, 
  CASE WHEN Z.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IS_FOREIGN_KEY 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME, TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC 
        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE As CCU ON CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        WHERE TC.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA AND TC.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME 
        AND (TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' or TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY') 
        AND CCU.COLUMN_NAME = C.COLUMN_NAME)
    AS PKEY
   ON Z.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME, TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC 
        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE As CCU ON CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        WHERE TC.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA AND TC.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME 
        AND (TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' or TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY') 
        AND CCU.COLUMN_NAME = C.COLUMN_NAME)
    AS FKEY
   ON Z.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'ProductExpert' 
AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Learning' 
ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

or alternatively you can use max with group by

```
SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME, C.DATA_TYPE, C.IS_NULLABLE, max(CASE WHEN Z.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IS_PRIMARY_KEY, 
max(CASE WHEN Z.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IS_FOREIGN_KEY 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C 
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME, TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC 
        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE As CCU ON CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        WHERE TC.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA AND TC.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME 
        AND (TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' or TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY') 
        AND CCU.COLUMN_NAME = C.COLUMN_NAME)
    AS Z 
WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'ProductExpert' 
AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Learning' 
group by C.COLUMN_NAME, C.DATA_TYPE, C.IS_NULLABLE, C.ORDINAL_POSITION 
ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: I used your second example with the group by and max. I had to move the order by under the group by and also add C.ORDINAL_POSITION to the group by claus to get it to run correctly - but this got me going. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for sytactical errors. I am glad that it is worked.